# Multiple objects handling in ToolTip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

If I have 3 objects in my array, Kendo UI does not show any tooltips. However, if I have only two objects in the array, it works fine.

Here is the code:

```
$("#chart").kendoChart({
    xAxis: {},
    yAxis: {},
    seriesDefaults: {type: "scatterLine" },
    series: [{data: stats}],
    tooltip:{visible:true}
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/52/) is the fiddle with three objects.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/51/) is the fiddle with two objects.

Comment: What's the third object for? Do you want multiple axis?

Comment: @Vash, No I have x and y axis only, but the main point, I would like to display three values on tooltip.

Comment: first and second object is for x and y accordingly. And the last object I would like to show it on tooltip along with first and second object.

Comment: Ok, I have got it and posted below, thanks  a lot Vash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/62/) is the answer:

First I should change the array of object to regular javascript object then it works.

```
var stats = [
    [0 , 200,400], [100, 300,900],[220, 400,1000],[300, 500,1500],[400, 800,1700],[600, 1200,1800],[800, 1600,3000]
];

stats = stats.map(function(x) {
    return { x: x[0], y: x[1], k: x[2] };
});

function createChart() {
    $("#chart")
        .kendoChart({
            xAxis: {},
            yAxis: {},
            seriesDefaults: {type: "scatterLine" },
            series: [{data: stats}],
            tooltip:{visible:true,template: "x : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.x)))#, y : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.y)))#, k : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.k)))# "}
        });
}


$(document)
    .ready(createChart);
```